# bash: how to do inline substitution/ expansion?

Tags: bash, shell

I run a script 
./script.sh  , e.g.

```
./script config.txt 480
```

which invoices something like

```
command --crf "${crf##*=}"
```

It reads from a config file. The config file contains several parameters, named in a pattern: `<parameter1><number>=<value>`,
e.g.

```
crf480=18.2
crf720=18.5
(…)
```

Right now, I include some lines at the script's beginning:

```
<An IFS that reads the config>
crf=$(cat "$config"|grep crf|grep $2)
qcomp=$(cat "$config"|grep qcomp|grep $2)
aqmode=$(cat "$config"|grep aqmode|grep $2)
…
```

so with ./script config.txt 480
$crf has the desired value (that of crf480).

I'd like to avoid that long list at the beginning and do the substitution/ expansion inline, so that "$crf" is expanded to "$crf480", depending on $2.
I spent some time on [https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/) and searched this site here, but as I am not a native speaker and a quite limited knowledge of bash, I didn't manage to find a solution.

Is it possible to do such inline substitution in bash and if yes, how to do it?

Comment: There is no substitution happening here. You are just reading data from input file and setting some variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read each line of the config and set the variable if the suffix is what you're looking for:

```
$ cat script
#!/bin/bash

suffix="$1"

# Read each name/value pair
while IFS="=" read -r name value
do
  # Check if the name ends with our chosen suffix
  if [[ $name == *"$suffix" ]]
  then
    # Set the variable name without the suffix
    declare "${name%"$suffix"}=$value"
  fi
done < config

echo "\$var contains $var"
```

If `config` contains the following:

```
$ cat config
var480=four eighty
var720=seven twenty
```

You can run the script like this:

```
$ ./script 480
$var contains four eighty

$ ./script 720
$var contains seven twenty
```